# How to resolve a recursive nested tree in jsonb?

Tags: json, postgresql, tree, breadth-first-search, jsonb

So I have a flattened tree like this:

```
[{
    aid: "id3"
    atype: ""
    data: ["id1", "id2"]
},

{
    aid: "id1"
    atype: ""
    data: ["id3", "id2"]
},

{
    aid: "id2"
    atype: ""
    bdata: {aid: "id4", atype: "nested", data: ["id1", "id3"]}
    data: []
}]
```

I want to gather that tree and resolve ids into data with recursion loops into something like this (say we start from `"id3"`):

```
{
    aid: "id3"
    payload: "1"
    data: [ 
    "id1":{
        aid: "id1"
        atype: ""
        data: ["id3":Null, "id2":Null]
    },
    "id2":{
            aid: "id2"
            atype: ""
            bdata: {aid: "id4", atype: "nested", data: ["id1":Null, "id3":Null]}
            data: []
    }]
}
```

So that we would get breadth-first search and resolve some field into `"value": "object with that field"` on first entrance and `"value": Null`

So How can one implement such a list to a tree in Postgres JSONb\ [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)?

I understand one could do it using something like PL/Python yet I failed to see a PL/Python function example that could do such a thing as not putting all JSON records into ram...

```
{'id1': {'aid': 'id1', 'atype': '', 'data': ['id3', 'id2']},
 'id2': {'aid': 'id2',
  'atype': '',
  'bdata': {'aid': 'id4', 'atype': 'nested', 'data': ['id1', 'id3']},
  'data': []},
 'id3': {'aid': 'id3', 'atype': '', 'data': ['id1', 'id2']}}
```

Is not really usable for me - So I need a real tree.

Comment: this is not a valid json format (your first json), so you can't

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your approach.

Let's consider following json.

```
  {
    "aid": "id3",
    "atype": "",
    "data": ["id1", "id2"]
  },

  {
    "aid": "id4",
    "atype": "",
    "data": ["id1", "id2"]
  }
```

**Here, id1 and id2 data need to be copied again for id4, It creates lot of duplicate data.**

Instead of that, convert your data to dictionary.
You can access the data just by calling the id’s like “id1”, “id2” and so on.

```
data_map = {}
for data in data_array:
   data_map.__setitem__(data['aid'], data)
```

Following will be sample output.

```
{
  "id3": {
  "aid": "id3",
  "atype": "",
  "data": [
    "id1", "id2"
  ]
}
```

This way you can access the id’s directly and don’t have duplicates in the structure.

**Complete sample code**

```
import json

json_data = '''
[
  {
    "aid": "id3",
    "atype": "",
    "data": ["id1", "id2"]
  },

  {
    "aid": "id1",
    "atype": "",
    "data": ["id3", "id2"]
  },

  {
    "aid": "id2",
    "atype": "",
    "bdata": {"aid": "id4", "atype": "nested", "data": ["id1", "id3"]},
    "data": []
  }
]
'''
data_array = json.loads(json_data)

data_map = {}
for data in data_array:
    data_map.__setitem__(data['aid'], data)

print(data_map)
```